# Draw images on canvas at different rates

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

Given two different images (say `image A` and `image B`), let's say I want to draw `image A` on a canvas at a rate of about 60 FPS and I want to draw `image B` at about 30 FPS.

My question is, using *requestAnimationFrame* what is the best way to do this? Should I create 2 canvases?

Comment: the callback of `requestAnimationFrame` receives a timestamp as its first argument. Use that timestamp to compute the time that passed between the last and the current execution of the callback and draw according to that.

Comment: @le_m but I should use 2 canvases for that, right?

Comment: You just need to keep track of two times. You don't need an additional canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback of `requestAnimationFrame` receives a timestamp as its first argument. Use that timestamp to compute the time that passed between the last and the current execution of the callback and draw according to that.

Here is a simple example demonstrating the above principle:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let last100 = 0;
let last500 = 0;

function frame(time) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.random() * 255 + ', 0, 0)';
  
  // 10 frames per second (1000/10 = 100):
  if (time > last100 + 100) {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    last100 = time;
  }
  
  // 2 frames per second (1000/2 = 500):
  if (time > last500 + 500) {
    ctx.fillRect(200, 0, 100, 100);
    last500 = time;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use 2 canvases but make them act as layers, i.e. "stack them" using absolute positioning.

There is [a helpful article here, written by](https://html5.litten.com/using-multiple-html5-canvases-as-layers/) [James Litten](https://plus.google.com/103786774022787740081?rel=author)

I started a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/hkcmeyek/); it would need a bit of tweaking to suit your needs (code same as snippet)

```js
var layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
var layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
var ctx1 = layer1.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = layer2.getContext("2d");

var img1 = loadImage('http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/purpleflowers.jpg', main);
var img2 = loadImage('http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg', main);

var imagesLoaded = 0;

function main() {
  imagesLoaded += 1;

  if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
    // set alpha for individual images as desired
    ctx1.globalAlpha = 0.8;
    ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.5;
     drawAll();
  }
}

function draw1() {
  frameRate = 30;
  ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, 250, 150);
  ctx1.beginPath();
  ctx1.rect(0, 0, 250, 150);
  ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0); //draw 1st image
  ctx1.closePath();
}

function draw2() {
  frameRate = 60;
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 250, 150);
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.rect(0, 0, 250, 150);
  ctx2.drawImage(img2, 0, 0); //draw 2nd image
  ctx2.closePath();
}

function drawAll() {
  draw1();
  draw2();
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = onload;
  img.src = src;

  return img;
}
```

```css
#layer1,
#layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="layer1">

</canvas>
<canvas id="layer2">

</canvas>
```

Comment: James uses setInterval when drawing his layers. It is not used in the above code.

Comment: Yeah, my plan was to overlay two canvases, but a little tweaking on @le_m code can accomplish that